# How to do Django unit testing - to reuse data from 1 Database via 1 class

Tags: django, database, unit-testing, django-testing, django-tests

As you can see in the setUpClass we define user and profile.

When you look at the method:

```
test_create_project
```

All is working fine and the test passes. Idea is since the Project and Position was created via that method, I would like to use it from DB in the method:

```
test_homepage
```

Problem is when you try to read them from DB they do not exist anymore. My question is why. I know if I create project in the

```
setUpClass
```

then it would be in the DB. My point is not to create extra Project and Position if I can create it via that method 1st - test it and then reuse it in the next one - but not via using (self) but by reading from DB.

Question1:

```
Is that possible?
```

Question2:

```
Are methods in this class using separated DBes?
```

Question3:

```
What is the most efficient - and proper approach to this - my point is not to create extra records and reuse data as we go.
```

These coming out empty in the test_homepage method:

```
    print(project)
    print(positions)
```

Django 2.2 Tests:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import TestCase
from django.utils import timezone

from stb.core.models import Profile, Skill, Project, Position

class EntireAppTest(TestCase):

    """Updating Profile"""

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        """Creating User"""
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='johnconnor',
            email='dude@nasa.gov',
            password='terminator'
        )
        cls.profile = Profile.objects.get(user=cls.user)
        skill = Skill()
        skill.save()
        skill.profile.add(cls.profile.id)
        skill.title='python'
        skill.save()

    def setUp(self):
        self.client.login(username='johnconnor', password='terminator')


    def test_create_account(self):
        self.user = User.objects.get(email='dude@nasa.gov')
        self.assertEqual(User.objects.count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(self.user.username, 'johnconnor')
        self.assertEqual(self.user.email, 'dude@nasa.gov')


    def test_create_profile(self):
        self.profile = Profile.objects.get(user=self.user)
        now = timezone.now()
        self.assertLess(self.profile.pub_date, now)

    def test_create_project(self):
        url = '/project/new/'
        response = self.client.post(
            url,
            data={
                'profile': self.profile,
                'title': 'NASA JPL',
                'position_formset-TOTAL_FORMS': 1,
                'position_formset-INITIAL_FORMS': 0,
                'position_formset-0-title': 'Python Developer',
                'position_formset-0-description': 'description',
            },
        )
        project = Project.objects.get(id=1)
        position = Position.objects.get(project=project)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertEqual(project.title, 'NASA JPL')
        self.assertEqual(position.title, 'Python Developer')

    def test_homepage(self):
        url = '/'
        response = self.client.get(
            url,
            data={},
        )
        positions = Position.objects.all()
        project = Project.objects.all()
        print(project)
        print(positions)
        # print(response.context)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```